# how to change timezone setting in Lucid Work Enterprises

Tags: solr, timezone, ubuntu-10.04

I have installed Lucid Work Enterprises and notice that its displaying time of UTC zone. But my system timezone is `UTC+05:30`. so there is always a difference in my database last_modified field value for delta query for indexing (as there is 5:30 Hrs difference in Lucid admin timezone and my database timezone).

I tried to  change a setting in start.bat file from 
`"set MISC_OPTS2=-Duser.language=en -Duser.country=US -Duser.timezone=UTC -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8"`
to 
`"set MISC_OPTS2=-Duser.language=en -Duser.country=US -Duser.timezone=UTC+05:30 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8"`

But it doesn't make any difference.

I am unable to find a way to change timezone setting in Lucid admin area. Even there was no option to select timezone in installation wizard.

Please help me that how i can change this timezone setting for Lucid.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue using lucen/solr (without LWE). At solr ther is (also) no way to configure the timezone. Asking an Partner from "Lucid imagination" how to handle time-zones with lucene/solr, i get the answer: change timezone-settings at your J2EE servlet container options.
But as you said:

> But it doesn't make any difference.

My workaround is realized by the application, which handles the "time-zone-difference" between lucene- and database timestamp. Not sure, which programming language you are using. PHP for example provides nice build-in functionality for handling dateTime objects and different timezones.